# Position JLabels underneath each other

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

For my application I am creating a script editor. At the moment I have the line numbers displaying in a JPanel containing represented by JLabels. However, when I add new `JLabels` to represent new line numbers, the `JLabels` appear on the center of the panel, even when I set the `JLabel's` `setVerticalAlignment` and `setVerticalTextPosition`. I want it so that the labels would appear underneath each other.

The JPanel class constructor which holds all the JLabels:

```
public LineNumberPanel() {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    //setup the label
    label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(lineCount));
    label.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 15));

    //setup the label alignment
    label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
    setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);

    add(label);
}
```

The method which is used to add JLabels to the JPanel:

```
public void increaseLineNumber() {
    lineCount++;

    JLabel tempLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(lineCount));
    tempLabel.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 15));

    tempLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
    tempLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    tempLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);

    revalidate();
    this.add(tempLabel);
}
```

What the it currently looks like when adding new JLabels:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `GridLayout`. It will stretch your components. If you use a `BoxLayout` it won't

A convenience class for `BoxLayout` is `Box`. You can do

```
Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
add(box);
```

Then just add the labels to the `box`

```
box.add(label);
```

**Example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class BoxLabels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
                Font font = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 11);

                JPanel sideBar = new JPanel();
                sideBar.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                sideBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
                sideBar.add(box);

                JTextArea text = new JTextArea(15, 50);
                text.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
                text.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
                text.setForeground(Color.white);
                text.setFont(font);

                int count = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(count));
                    label.setFont(font);
                    label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                    box.add(label);
                    count++;
                }

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                panel.add(text);
                panel.add(sideBar, BorderLayout.WEST);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

See more [**How to use BoxLayout**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) and other Layout Managers at [**Laying out Components Within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the PreferedSize of the Labels accordingly. Unfortunately it isn't clear which LayoutManager you use.

Comment: I have used the GridLayout(0,1); on the main panel, but have not applied a LayoutManager to the JLabels.

Comment: Do you add the Labels to the ContentPane or do you have an extra JPanel for the Labels?

Comment: I add the labels to the JPanel within which they are instantiated in. I then add that JPanel to the JPanel containing the JTextArea to combine both of them to get the script editor appearance.

Comment: There is no problem in using a GridLayout for your ContentPane, as long as you use a LayoutManager for the Panel which contains the JLabels, which doesn't resize the components in the Panel. A BoxLayout or a FlowLayout would be a good choice. Even the GridLayout should be ok if you simply add more Labels indicating empty lines

Comment: Ok... so the solution would be to change the LayoutManager of the panel which contains the JLabels to something different, i.e. a BoxLayout. For even more Control your could use a GridBayLayout or an absolute Layout. Don't forget to set the size of the JLabels accordingly.